# Script for Dropbox to make a automatic process

Tags: java, algorithm, dropbox

Hope you all know about Dropbox. In Dropbox, we can drag the files to drop box folder then it will be stored in the cloud. I need to do this  manual process (Drag and drop to the Dropbox folder) through a script. The script must allow the same task once the user defined the file extensions. In other words, drag and drop to the Dropbox folder must be an automatic process through a script once the user define the file types (extensions).

How can I achieve this? *Note:* I'm using java to get job done.

*All comments are welcome.*

Answer (score 2):

```
File f = new File(myDirString);
File[] files = f.listFiles();
foreach (File aFile in files)
    if (someRegex.match(aFile.getName())
        // use FileWriter to copy contents of file to a new file in Dropbox directory
```

This is a broken down example (brain compiled so I might have messed something up) but its hopefully enough to get you started

Answer (score 0):

use a script to move/copy the desired file into your dropbox directory? Java has a filesystem API i believe.